# Access a dynamically created view by its tag id

Tags: swift, uiview

Is there a way to have a view created in a for loop accessed by its tag id? If not is there a better way to achieve the below? My guess is that because I am overwriting the 'myView' var that it will always be the last value of the for loop. But is there a way to achieve something like this below? [Swift]

```
var myView = UIView();

// Create a for loop of 20 Views on different x/y axis
var myView = UIView();
var leftPos : CGFloat = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    myView.tag = i;
    myView.frame = CGRect(x: leftPos, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    mySuperView.addSubview(myView)
    leftPos += 20;
}
// Then later on reference it by its tag id:
myView.tag[13].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a view with a specific tag using the `viewWithTag` function:

```
view = mySuperView.viewWithTag(13)
```

Note that using a tag of 0 is "bad" since that's the default tag value if no other value is used.

Comment: Ahhhh so simple I knew it was something easy. Thanks so much David!

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned the default tag value. :)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using tags, I suggest a better solution is to keep an array of your views that you can reference by index instead.

```
// Declare a variable to hold on to your subviews
var views = [UIView]()

// Create 20 views, add them as subviews and add them to the views array
for i in 0..<20 {
    let leftPos = CGFloat(i) * 20

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: leftPos, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    mySuperView.addSubview(view)
    views.append(view)
}

// Access the view by it's index - no need for a tag.
views[13].backgroundColor = .redColor()
```

Comment: This is a great idea! Thanks Abizern!

Comment: This is probably a better approach. I was just answering the question asked :)

Comment: You saved my struggling with autoLayout and scrollView, thank you.